# Second vm not connecting to internet KVM

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization

I cannot connect a second VM to the internet.

I have two VM's set up and running, the first vm can connect to the Internet fine, the second does not even get a ping through. They are both set up in the same way with the same base packages but different secondary packages. Different sized disks etc.

I am a noob with VM and perhaps I am missing something very simple. Like maybe that they have the same mac address or something.

They are both using a bridged connection.

Any help would be appreciated, and if you need logs please let me know which ones.

Comment: Are the VM's running on a server of their own, under a Windows or Mac installation or something else?

Comment: He said KVM, it's going to be a Linux box.

Comment: Yes they are running on their own server and yes it is on a linux box.

Comment: Well, checking the MAC addresses would be a good first step.  Also, check the subnet mask/gateway on both of them and ensure they are correct.

Comment: What is the result of `brctl show` command ? and what is the kvm launcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is what I've learnt about using vmbuilder in the last few days, but didn't find much in the way of information about. This works for me, but may not work for everybody

1. Always use the --gw switch pointing to your gateway.
2. Always use the -d (destination) switch with a unique name for each vm you are creating
3. Install apt-cacher-ng (on linux) and use the --proxy switch pointing to the apt-cacher server

The reason I had trouble with some items not connecting to the internet was because the gateway was not set in the command.